# Images not appearing in browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

I have images that I am trying to include in my application that for some reason I cannot get to render. Usually when I include images in a project I link to them from Unsplash or another image hosting site.

For this project I wanted to use my own images and include the files within my directory rather than uploading them to imgur and linking to them.

This is what I tried...

I placed the images in the rails images directory and then created a thumbs directory within the images directory and included the same pictures.

I then tried linking to them in my gallery.html.erb file like so.

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="assets/images/thumbs/one.jpg" alt="assets/images/one.jpg"/>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img src="app/assets/images/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="app/assets/images/2.jpg"/>
</a>
```

The file path seems to be right to me unless I am missing something, but in my browser they are not appearing.  I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<%= image_tag("/thumbs/one.jpg", size: "100x100", alt: "text") %>
```

Comment: I up vote this...your path written as a string might not be quit right for the image location based on the asset pipeline...using image_tag will fix it...if that is the problem.  Definitely the first thing to try...

Answer (score 0):

maybe your html file and theL `asset/..` && `apps/..` is not in the same folder.